# Firebase Login with React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

The basic idea is to make a Firebase Login in React.

The components render itself, but they're not working together. The main problem is that the render function doesn't take the «new» states, after the onAuthStateChanged() method is called. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you a lot guys!

```
var Login = React.createClass ({

  getInitialState: function(){
        return { loggedIn: 'false' };
    },

    handleLogIn: function(event){

      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // ERROR HANDLING
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message; 

        // [... error handling ...]   

      });

      this.setState({ loggedIn: 'true' });

    },

  authenticateUser: function(x){

    // INITIALIZATION
    var config = {
      [ ... config stuff ... ]
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //CHECKING IF SIGNED IN
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // USER IS SIGNED IN
        console.log('authenticateUser(): true');
        this.setState({ loggedIn: 'true' });
      }
      else {
        // USER IS SIGNED OUT
        console.log('authenticateUser(): false');
        this.setState({ loggedIn: 'false' });
      }
    });
  },

  whichWindowToShow: function() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn === 'unknown'){
      return (
        <div>
        <Loading type='bubbles' color='#e3e3e3' />
        </div>
      );
    }
    else if (this.state.loggedIn === 'true'){
      return (
        <div>
        <Backend />
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div className="login_wrapper">
        <div className="login_box">
        <h1>Member Login</h1>
          <div className="login_fields">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="mail"/>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <button id="signin" name="signin" onClick={this.handleLogIn}>Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    this.authenticateUser();
    return (
      <div>
        { this.whichWindowToShow() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}); // END LOGIN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all with the same problem/challenge:

THIS will work ( `.bind(this)` does fix the scope).

Should also be applied on all other Firebase listeners ( .on("value") for example )

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: "true" });
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: "false" });
  }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: or you can assign to a ```this.removeListener = firebase.auth()....``` and execute it in componentWillUnmount... your method is much more elegant though.