# firebase :: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

Hello i am trying to use react-router with firebase. but it gives me this error.

> Cannot read property 'props' of null

this is exactly code, where i am using my react-router

Down code is on component as loginpanel component.

```
else if (this.email.value === currentObject.username && this.password.value === currentObject.password && user_id)
 {
     var data25 = '';
     var groupid = '';

     var query = firebase.database().ref("/Users_group").orderByChild('id').equalTo(user_id);
     query.on("child_added", function hello (snapshot) {

         data25 = snapshot.val();

         groupid = data25.User_Group_id;

         AppActions.createComment(currentObject.username, currentObject.password, user_id, groupid);

//error is here,

         this.props.router.push('Index');
     },()=>{

     });

 }
```

my react router is declared on main.jsx
my react-router looks like this.

```
       <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Loginpanel}/>
      <Route path="Index" component={Index}/>
      <Route path="Form" component={Form} />
      <Route path="Checkindex" component={Index}/>
      <Route path="Signup" component={Signup}/>
      <Route path="Admin" component={Admin}/>
      <Route path="AdminEditDetails" component={AdminEditDetails}/>
      <Route path="AdminDetails" component={AdminDetails}/>

     </Router>,
```

Comment: and which component is that code from, and which function, and where is that function called, and what is the relevance of the first snippet of code? Please post a more complete code sample, also you used push wrongly

Comment: its code from Loginpanel component.

Comment: my browser is pointing the error towards this   this.props.router.push('Index'); .... can you guide me why push is wrongly used and my code is on loginpanel page and and with this elseif i am trying to go to another component name as Index

Comment: @DominicTobias  Can you help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback, the `this` pointer no longer points to your React component. There are many ways to deal with this:

#### Capture `this` into another variable

```
var component = this;
query.on("child_added", function hello (snapshot) {
    ...
    component.props.router.push('Index');
});
```

#### Explicitly bind `this`

```
query.on("child_added", function hello (snapshot) {
    ...
    this.props.router.push('Index');
}).bind(this);
```

#### Use fat arrows, which implicitly keeps `this`

```
query.on("child_added", snapshot => {
    ...
    this.props.router.push('Index');
});
```

Note that this is a very common problem that developers have in JavaScript and I highly recommend you learn more about the way `this` behaves with callbacks:

- [Polymer this.push not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306772/polymer-this-push-not-working/39308178#39308178)
- [how to call a function inside a self-executing anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963644/how-to-call-a-function-inside-a-self-executing-anonymous-function/35964368#35964368)
- [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)
- [Firebase Login with React Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226238/firebase-login-with-react-components/38328015#38328015)