# Can't access my store from within Firebase promise

Tags: firebase, vue.js, scope, firebase-authentication

Within the promise attached to `Firebase`'s `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function I'm trying to access a mutation function from my store, but I get the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined"

Why and how to solve this problem?

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'Signup',
  data: function() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signUp: function() {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
        function(user) {
          alert('Your account has been created!');
          this.$store.userConnectedUpdate('true');
        },
        function(error) {
          alert('Oops. ' + error.message)
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the callback function `this` has a different meaning. There are a few broad solutions to this, but the simplest one is to use `=>` notation:

```
signUp: function() {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(() => {
      alert('Your account has been created!');
      this.$store.userConnectedUpdate('true');
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Oops. ' + error.message)
    }
  );
}
```

See my answer here for the other options: [firebase :: Cannot read property 'props' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366143/firebase-cannot-read-property-props-of-null/39372248#39372248)